# How do I redirect terminal output from a C program to System.out with JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, stdout

I am invoking a C library via JNI that prints to stdout.  How can I redirect this output to System.out?

Answer (score 8):

`System.out` **is** `stdout`.  Is there some more fundamental problem you're having (mixed up output, perhaps?).

Since another member has also mentioned that last point - I should explain further:

`System.out` and `stdout` both correspond to file descriptor #1.

However both Java's `OutputStream` (and derived classes) and C's `stdio` library have their own (independent) buffering mechanisms so as to reduce the number of calls to the underlying `write` system call.  Just because you've called `printf` or similar, it's not guaranteed that your output will appear straightaway.

Because these buffering methods are independent, output from within Java code could (in theory) get mixed up or otherwise appear out-of-order relative to output from the C code.

If that's a concern, you should arrange to call `System.out.flush()` before calling your JNI function, and in your C function (if it's using `stdio` rather than the low-level `write` call) you should call `fflush(stdout)` before returning.

Comment: Yes but if you change your `System.out` variable in the JVM and call native C code, the output of the C method will still be written to the terminal while your java output may be directed elsewhere. If you know a workaround for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As Alnitak wrote, you should print to stdout. You should note that it can take a while for the message to appear on the screen. In case the timing is important, you should print a timestamp with the message when you print to stdout.