# Execution of static methods from native c code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, execution

I have to call some static java methods from c.

```
SOME-C-CODE
(*g_env)->CallStaticVoidMethodA(g_env, g_obj, g_mid, val);
SOME-C-CODE
(*g_env)->CallStaticVoidMethodA(g_env, g_obj, g_mid, val);
SOME-C-CODE
(*g_env)->CallStaticVoidMethodA(g_env, g_obj, g_mid, val);
SOME-C-CODE
```

I have to call java methods several times at different places. But the code executes all the java methods first and then comes to executing the native code.
Please tell me how I can run the code in the execution sequence required ?

P.S. I've cached the jvm, jobject and jmethod and attaching them to current thread using AttachCurrentThread and DetachCurrentThread

Comment: How do you know that all Java methods are executing first? If you just printing logs to console, you need to know that Java System.out.println() and C printf() are buffered, and they have different buffers, so your output might be just messed up, so you might need to call System.out.flush() and fflush(stdout) each time you print a line of text.

Comment: Thanks a lot @pelya. The problem was related to buffer and it is working now

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I redirect terminal output from a C program to System.out with JNI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290743/how-do-i-redirect-terminal-output-from-a-c-program-to-system-out-with-jni)